# Add shared network drive to Windows with "xxx GB free of yyy GB" bar

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I currently have a server running Server Ubuntu v16.04 with Samba installed. I can make a shared folder and access it from my Windows PC on network, just fine. Obviously, I can set the folder location to be the location of the mounted drive, in order to have access to the entire drive. However, I was wondering if it's possible to add it *as a drive*, in the sense that Windows will read it as a drive and show me the bar telling me how much space is left on the drive, with the prompt reading "___ GB free of ___ GB" underneath, as it does with the attached drives.

Comment: I think you must "map" the network drive [like here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-network-drive-windows-10)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. If you can write this as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will show you this status line (XXX free of YYY) when the network drive is mapped (to a letter, like `n:`).

You can find some help [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-network-drive-windows-10), for how to mount a drive on Windows 10.